# signal propagates in bending transmission line (unequal length between signal path and return path)

Tags: electromagnetism, emc, transmission-line, power-engineering, signal-integrity

Suppose I have a square wave signal generated from a signal generator and its outputs are connected to the two terminals of a paired PCB traces (left side of the picture below). The other end of the paired PCB traces are connected to a oscilloscope. V+(I+) and V-(I-) should arrive the red dash line at the same time according to transmission line theory. However, the outer transmission line is longer than the inner transmission line because of the bend, thus, V- travels a longer distance than V+, so should I see a the two signals appears on the oscilloscope in different time with V+ arrives at oscilloscope earlier? I don't think this is right, but I cannot think of a reason why. My gut feelings tell me that the two signal should arrive at oscilloscope at the same time, but I cannot explain it in physics. Can anyone help me to explain it? Thanks[image]

Comment: it depends whether (1) your V+ and V- conductors are each a transmission line with ground with little coupling between them, or (2) the ground is remote and they are tightly coupled, or (3) some situation intermediate between the two. In case 1, both signals will arrive at different times, each with respect to ground. In case two, *the signal*, the differential signal, will arrive at the scope.

Comment: @Neil_UK, but even in situation (2) the differential signal would be distorted and/or coupled into a common-mode signal by the mismatch.

Comment: @Neil_UK, what if my V- is ground?

Comment: @Neil_UK, recently I've been thinking your case 3, can you please elaborate more what will happen in case 3? Would be perfect if you can shows some examples. Thank you!

Comment: The result will be intermediate between the two. Get a circuit simulator, LTSpice is good, free, widely supported, and have a play.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> However, the outer transmission line is longer than the inner transmission line because of the bend, thus, V- travels a longer distance than V+, so should I see a the two signals appears on the oscilloscope in different time with V+ arrives at oscilloscope earlier?

Yes, this can happen.

It also causes differential-to-common-mode conversion which can be bad for EMC.

But it's normally only a significant problem for signal frequencies above 2 GHz or so.

Reducing this effect is why you'll sometimes see a differential pair with a serpentine in one trace but not the other:

[image]

([image source](https://www.onsemi.com/pub/Collateral/AN-6103-D.PDF))

Comment: thanks for your prompt response! I have a follow up question if you don't mind to answer. In your attached picture, the purpose of serpentine is to make the differential line has equal length, the downside is that it causes impedance mismatch since the space between two lines changes here and there because of it, am I thinking right?

Comment: @WenhaoChen, if you're being very fussy, you can make the track segments on both lines slightly wider where the tracks are separated, to maintain the Z0. (You'd basically use the track width for separate single-ended lines) I've not seen anyone bother to do that for frequencies below maybe 10 GHz, though.

Comment: "But it's normally only a significant problem for signal frequencies above 2 GHz or so".  On typical bench-sized setups.  Run the cables the length of a 747 and the "don't care" frequency range will be different.  Run the cables from San Diego to Yreka California, and the frequency range will be different yet.

Comment: @TimWescott, I was thinking that very few people build circuit boards that reach from San Diego to Yreka. But now I see the question is tagged as [power-engineering], so maybe that is an important application to keep in mind.

Comment: @Tim, and in the 747 scenario, it doesn't really matter what's the total length of the line. A single bend, like presented in the question, will produce the same length mismatch regardless.

Comment: @ThePhoton True.  Ish.  A single bend [i]with the same spacing[/i] will produce the same difference.  But some big thing (like a factory floor, or an entire state) has more room for bends with bigger spacing.  If it's really power engineering, and you take the "1/10 \$\lambda\$ gets important" rule of thumb, then a disparity of 500km matters on a 60Hz grid.

Comment: @ThePhoton, at my lunch, I was thinking "make the track segments on both lines slightly wider where the tracks are separated" in your previous comments, wouldn't this affect the effective total length of two lines?

Comment: It may affect the total effective length.  More importantly, if the size of the feature is a significant fraction of a wavelength, it keeps the effective *impedance* of the line constant, to avoid turning what ought to be a nice flat transmission line pair into a filter.

Comment: @TimWescott, so it's really a trade-off between matching impedance or the synchronization of differential signals. For example, we need equal length paired traces if we need the differential signal to arrive at the same time at the termination, on the other hand, we need equal spaced paired traces if we want nice and clean signal. Ultimately, we want both but sometimes we have to trade-off, sorry for being fussy.

Comment: @Vincent_CHEN, The change in effective length due to widening the traces will likely be negligible compared to the effect of the serpentine itself. If you really need to know the effect, you could model the whole thing in an EM simulator.

Comment: @ThePhoton, thanks! Any recommendations for free EM solvers to play with?

Comment: @Vincent_CHEN, sorry I don't know any good free ones. Qucs might let you do most of what you want, with higher level modeling.

Comment: @ThePhoton, after reviewing your attached picture of BGA trace routing, there's one more question came to my mind and hopefully you have the answer. Take the orange paired lines on the very left side as an example, I understand that the total length are kept the same on purpose to let the signals arrive at the terminal at the same time, however, if I only focus on the section before the "90 degree" turn, the trace on the right is actually longer than the left one, so the signal on the left trace should be ahead of the signal on the right trace, what is the consequence of this? bad integrity?

Comment: @Vincent_CHEN, I don't think it's critical whether the serpentines are "before" or "after" the bend they're compensating for. Main goal is to get the overall trace lengths matched. Practically, there is no perfect layout. But engineering isn't about making things perfect --- it's about making something that is useful for a reasonable cost.

Comment: @ThePhoton, understand that is not critical. Just out of curiosity what would happen if the signal on one trace is locally ahead of the other. (but globally arrive at the terminal at the same time)

Comment: Ideally, nothing happens. The receiver sees just the signal it expects. One way to look at this is you coupled the differential signal into a common mode one, and then back. One risk is that the common mode signal produces radiated emissions. How much emissions? Depends on details, details, details.

Comment: @ThePhoton Thank you! Your answer helps a lot!